# Magento 2.4 how to add custom attribute in sidebar

Tags: product-attribute, sidebar, magento2.4.3.p1

**Magento 2.4 how to add custom attribute in sidebar**

I have created some attributes for my products and I want to display them in the sidebar
I looked and tested most of the posts on the site, unfortunately it did not work
I use Magento 2.4.3
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use the below option for your custom attribute from Admin.

Stores->Attributes->Product->Search for your Custom Attribute

[image]

Hope you find this useful.